# SharePoint 2010 project incompatible in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, visual-studio-2015, sharepoint-2013

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 (Professional). But when I open SharePoint 2010 project on VS 2015, it's showing project is incompatible.

Could you please tell any solution or idea to load the project in VS 2015?

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the VS error to your question, so other users recognize the error faster, if the visit this site?

Comment: @Serv, I didn't took any screenshot before. After following your instructions it works fine. Thanks for remembering this, It will be helpful in near future if I reproduce the problem again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your project is not loading because Microsoft Office Developer Tools is not installed on your machine. You can easily modify your visual studio 2015 by following steps:

1. Run Visual Studio 2015 Setup File
2. Click on modify

[image]

3. Find the “**Microsoft Office Developer Tools**” and select it.

[image]

4. Finally click on Update.

After completing the setup open your project.

Answer (score 3):

When you install VS2015, you do not install the mandatory [Office Development Tools for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.aspx).

Once, you have downloaded and installed those. (Around 78MB) your SharePoint projects should, once again, load up without any errors.

Direct Link to the latest version:

- http://aka.ms/getlatestofficedevtools